# jQuery loop an "add class" method with a delay between

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am now creating a site including several sections with elements appearing with "cascade" style (one after the other, with a delay between). This is the way I do it:

```
setTimeout(function(){
         $('nav .icon-hola').toggleClass('colorHigh');      },300);     
      setTimeout(function(){
         $('nav .icon-progra').toggleClass('colorHigh');      },400);          
      setTimeout(function(){
         $('nav .icon-sistemas').toggleClass('colorHigh');      },500);       
      setTimeout(function(){
         $('nav .icon-equipo').toggleClass('colorHigh');       },600);   
            setTimeout(function(){
         $('nav .icon-clases').toggleClass('colorHigh');      },700); 
      setTimeout(function(){
         $('nav .icon-social').toggleClass('colorHigh');      },800);       
      setTimeout(function(){
         $('nav .icon-contacto').toggleClass('colorHigh');       },900);
```

Is there any way of creating some kind of loop that, in this case, gives every `$('nav [class^=icon-]')` an `.addClass('colorHigh')` method every 100 ms?

If there is, is it more reliable to do it by the way I am doing or by the other? Both need same resources or does one of those take more load to apply?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It will certainly save you some code,

http://jsbin.com/yujujucoviqi/1/edit

```
var delay = 300;
var targetSelectors = [
  'nav .icon-hola',
  'nav .icon-progra',
  'nav .icon-sistemas'
];
function showInDelay(targetSelectors, delay, incrementDelayBy){
  if(!incrementDelayBy){
    incrementDelayBy=100;
  }
  var elems = [];
  if($.type(targetSelectors)==="string"){
    elems = $(targetSelectors);
  }else{
    elems = $(targetSelectors.join());
  }
$(elems).each(function(index,selector){
  setTimeout(function(){console.log(selector);
         $(selector).toggleClass('colorHigh');      
  },delay+=incrementDelayBy);
});  

}

    /*call this for as many selectors eg nav bars you require*/
showInDelay(targetSelectors, delay);

/*or with a selector*/
//showInDelay("nav [class^=icon-]", delay);
```

Comment: I am about to try this.

Comment: Is not any way of making a selector without mentioning every element? They all are $('nav [class^=icon-]')

Comment: Ok I have just seen, iam about to try

Comment: Not very efficient imho. You're loading a number of timer events into the event loop (see http://vimeo.com/96425312, around the 10th minute), whilst you really only need one [at a time].

Comment: @Kooilnc +1 and thanks for the video. Although in this particular case I don't think it makes much difference, on the contrary I think there might be a better chance of having everything run closer on time as scheduled.

Comment: *I think there might be a better chance of having everything run closer on time as scheduled* - why would that be the case?

Comment: @Kooilnc possibly because the main thread would be less busy and the timers would run in separate threads as scheduled right away and placed in queue (just an assumption).

Answer (score 2):

This will do the work:

**EDITED CODE**

```
var delay=100;
$('nav [class^=icon-]').each(function(counter){
    //counter will start from 0..
    timeout = delay * (counter + 1);
    var selector = $(this);
    setTimeout(function(){
         selector.toggleClass('colorHigh');
    }, timeout);
});
```

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/k57425z6/2/)

Answer (score 0):

Here's a recursive method you could use:

```
function toggleTimed(els, time){
    var el = [].shift.call(els)
       ,fn = function () {
               $(el).toggleClass('colorHigh'); 
               if (els.length) {toggleTimed(els,time);}
             };
    if (el) { setTimeout(fn, time);}
}
```

Usage may be something like:

```
toggleTimed($('[class^=icon]'),400);
```

Here's a simple demo in [**jsFiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/KooiInc/L1ajewh7/)